# How to copy static html pages in gulp

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I am using nunjucks for my project. Now I have one HTML site with its own assets. I need to have it in my path `url/static_pages/page`.

But if I only copy it in the pages folder, the gulp build does not recognise it.

How can I make a simple gulp task that would copy the files from for example pages/static_pages/ into the /dist folder and have it on my correct path?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a copy of your Gulpfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example a gulp task to copy html pages:

**gulp.html.js**

```
module.exports.copy = function(){
    var src = [];
        src.push('static_pages/page/*.html');

    var dist = 'dist/pages/static_pages';

    return gulp.src(src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));

};
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var html = require('gulp.html');
gulptask('htmlcopy', html.copy);
```

You need to check your paths on your own. I cannot see if you use the right paths.